# IPSEC-tools config

Tags: ipsec

Once I run setkey with the following config file,

```
add 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 esp 2000 -E aes-ctr 0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333;
add 3.3.3.3 2.2.2.2 esp 2000 -E aes-ctr 0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333;
```

...it causes an error message (File Exists), and only one entry is shown with `setkey -D`. It seems that destination IP+SPI pair should be unique, (but multiple adds with the same source IP+SPI are OK), I wonder if it's intentional, and why ?

**UPDATE**:
It seems that for incoming IPSEC packets, add rules work **regardless of the source IP**. i.e. when I have any of the two rules above on host 2.2.2.2, incoming packets from any source IP with SPI 2000 are accepted and decrypted. This explains why I get the error message for the second line, but I still don't quite understand why the source IP is ignored.